# Return a substring of a string if exists

Tags: php, regex

I need to extract console platform from the description of products in CSV file.

I used regex to match all the console brands that are included in the list.

This is for WP All-Import plugin PHP editor widget.

```
$haystack = "NINTENDO MARIO KART 7 XBOX-360 SPECIAL EDITION";

echo preg_replace('/(\PS4\b)|(\bPS3\b)|(\bSWITCH\b)|(\bXBOX \b)|(\bXBOX-360\b)|(\bXBOX-ONE\b)|
(\bPC\b)|(\bPSP\b)|(\bWII \b)|(\bWII-U\b)|(\b3DS\b)|(\b2DS\b)|(\bNINTENDO-DS\b)/', '$1', $haystack);
```

I expect:
XBOX-360

It returns the rest of the string except what I expect:
NINTENDO MARIO KART 7 SPECIAL EDITION

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use preg_match. The $ result [0] variable will be the result

```
$haystack = "NINTENDO MARIO KART 7 XBOX-360 SPECIAL EDITION";

preg_match('/(\PS4\b)|(\bPS3\b)|(\bSWITCH\b)|(\bXBOX \b)|(\bXBOX-360\b)|(\bXBOX-ONE\b)|
(\bPC\b)|(\bPSP\b)|(\bWII \b)|(\bWII-U\b)|(\b3DS\b)|(\b2DS\b)|(\bNINTENDO-DS\b)/', $haystack, $result);
echo $result[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Please could someone elaborate on what you would put into the "Attribute" field to call the response. I have tried $result[0] which does not seem to work.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You have submitted an answer but you haven't provided any solution to the question above. If you'd like to ask anything please do it in a new question tab. Every user can submit new questions :)